# best practise - locking files and sharing between threads

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, locking, filestream

Background : I have a few different threads which each need to write to a log file (.txt). i need a way of sharing this file between the threads but i'm not sure how to go about doing this, i've read into perhaps using some sort of queue, and polling this queue to push the messages into the text file and such. Or do i need to lock files and just get the messages in a queue to be written after the one infront has finished?

Currently i'm writing like so;

```
  fileToWrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DeviceManager.logPath + correctDateTimeFormat);
```

But i'm getting the error message;

```
 The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process.
```

i can only assume multiple threads are trying to access this at the same time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what approach i should take with this?

Comment: maybe this fits you needs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

Comment: Go for Log4Net it already does this

Comment: log4net or (I prefer) NLog. While it isn't the answer to 'how do I lock these files the right way', it does solve the problem.

Comment: looking at Log4Net, is that not for WPF and not winforms? edit: perhaps it's just the tutorial i was looking at, will confirm shortly.

Comment: found some pretty swish tutorials for using Log4Net in winforms so i'll take a look at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are 2 different problems you are facing here with.

1. Opening a file again, before it is closed - this can be done by opening with appropriate sharing flags
2. Synchronizing access to it. This one can be done, by having some mutex to allow only 1 thread to access the file at a time. This is important, because otherwise, you might have threads write to a file simultaneously, which may cause problems, like messages crossing between self.

This [FileStream constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) with `FileSharing` parameter can help you with opening files from few threads, before closing them.

However, for your need, it would be better if you would centralize access to your file (for example, log file) in one place (make a class, that have one instance which will control access to this particular file) and make sure, it will synchronize access from different threads by locking some private mutex, so you will not write to file from few threads simultaneously.

Very simple example, which needs building up:

```
class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private FileStream file; //Only this instance have a right to own it
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private object mutex; //Mutex for synchronizing

    public Logger(string logPath)
    {
        file = new FileStream(logPath);
        writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        mutex = new object();
    }

    // Log is thread safe, it can be called from many threads
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
             writer.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
          writer.Dispose(); //Will close underlying stream
    }
}
```

Once again, it is very simple, only to show basic rule of what we are trying to achieve here.

Few other options you have here:

1. Use ready to use logging libraries (Log4Net or NLog (which I prefer personally))
2. Log may add message to a queue and you can have another thread, internal for logger reading messages from this queue and write them, this way, callers of Logger will not have to wait for a log message to finish logging

Comment: point 2 seems interesting, do you have any references i can look at in particular?

Comment: @Shane.C I have added some things to point 1 and 2. Nevertheless, if you only need logging functionality and you don't want to write own library for fun, it is better to use ready libraries, they work great and integrate easily with WinForms, WPF and any other apps.

Comment: thanks for your input : ) definitely shed some light on the situation, i think i'm going to just use log4net as these seems to be the favourite choice.

Comment: That's not a mutex. That's a critical section (which is the correct solution for this problem, but you're using the wrong terminology). Mutexes work across processes (not just threads) and that code won't. In order to use a Mutex, you would need to use System.Threading.Mutex.

Comment: @MNGwinn - locking on object uses Monitor class, which is not the same as critical section known from WinApi. Furthermore, Mutex you are referring to is a mutex, that's right, but mutex in it's definition is not "process wide" or does not refer to one particular WinApi object, Mutex is, by definition, a MUTual EXclusion object, which prevents simultaneous access to shared resource by many threads. So, there's nothing wrong in my opinion to call my object, that is used for such case a mutex, as it does what it should do.

Comment: @MNGwinn - Oh, and there are named mutexes and unnamed ones, the latter ones can't be used process wide as well. Furthermore, for this example, process wide lock is not needed.

Comment: A mutex, in the context of C#, is a very specific thing, as are critical sections. You're not using a mutex. This isn't ambiguous - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post for how do you use log4net in wpf 
http://codetechnics.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-configure-initialize-and-using.html
If you get error  ***The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

Because  **log4net** apparently needs access to ***system.web.dll***, which isn’t included in the **client profile**

Open your project’s properties page, and set the ***Target Framework*** to **.Net Framework 4** and save your changes.

Comment: is there a reason my log file seems to just be overfilling with [header][footer][header][footer] and so on and so forth?